# assigning data to dynamic list variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have requirement where I need to create dynamic json data.
For which i will get two values, columnName and columnValue

```
var filterJsonColumns = [];
var genericFilter = function (columnName , columnValue) {

    if (filterOn != "") {
        $scope.filterJsonColumns[columnName ].push(columnValue);
    }
    console.log("$scope.filterJsonColumns", $scope.filterJsonColumns);
}
```

For this case I am using dynamic variable for the creation of JSON 
ColumnName can have either status or stage or both.
So for in this case JSON should be like

**JSON**

```
filterJsonColumns={"status":["1","2"],"stage":["4","5"]}
```

This JSON formatting is not proper, but still I need this type of data.

Comment: Shouldn't the json be like: `filterJsonColumns={"status":["1","2"],"stage":["4","5"]}`

Comment: @mhu thanks for the correction

Comment: what is the problem here? Can you supply an example of what you get and what you expect?

Comment: please provide fiddle/plnkr.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
var filterJsonColumns = {};
var genericFilter = function (columnName , columnValue) {

if (filterOn != "") {
    if(!filterJsonColumns[columnName]){
        filterJsonColumns[columnName] = [];
    }
    filterJsonColumns[columnName].push(columnValue);
}
console.log("filterJsonColumns",filterJsonColumns);
```